# Forking (postgre)SQL database structure

Tags: sql, database, git, postgresql, version-control

I have been developing a network security application for several years now, as the lead developer at my company. It is a split-architecture design, where one component resides on the customer's network, and the other component in our own cloud. We have developed our own custom versioning system that keeps both sides synchronized at each patch (per customer), but until now it has only allowed incremental changes to be made, and rollbacks are not possible.

We'd like to move to a forkable git-like solution for our code, so that we can develop and test multiple features simultaneously, but the thing that's holding us back from that is our database. We use PostgreSQL (currently 9.3.12), and I've written a custom script to calculate the deltas between the "old" and "new" database structure, each time we "make a patch". It spits out a list of SQL commands necessary to update the "old" database structure to look like the "new", including tables, functions, sequences, triggers, you name it. It's very elegant and pretty much never fails anymore, even with complicated deltas.

However, I realize that in order to have a git-like solution for this (check-out, check-in, merge changes into test and production code, etc.) while also keeping database changes in sync with application code, we'll need to have something a lot more advanced than just "old" vs "new". Note that we don't need to modify database data for the most part, only table structure, which is altered in place on existing customer databases.

**So my question is this: Any ideas for a git-like SQL version control system, which allows forking and merging, and can be easily kept in sync with application code changes?** Our custom tool is already a bit more advanced than some open-source tools we've looked into (such as sqlt-diff), and tools like Red Gate are a bit out of our price range as a startup (not to mention that I haven't heard anybody mention forking in context with Red Gate). We're open to writing a custom tool, if that's what we need to do, but we're scratching our heads about where to start with something like that. We know how to calculate deltas, but we don't know how to manage all those things across different forks.

**Free or open-source tools, frameworks we can adapt, or general guiding principles for building such tools are all appreciated!**

Comment: I have not worked with them in this way, but possible that SQLAlchemy/Alembic may have features related to what you need: http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/branches.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of solving this problem is with migrations. A couple of lightweight tools, but there are many others:

http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/migration_rdoc.html

https://flywaydb.org/

Rather than calculating deltas between versions after the fact, migrations can be used to evolve the schema in a controlled way. You can create feature-specific migrations that can be tracked (and forked/merged) along with the rest of your code.

Depending on how fancy you want to get, you may need to extend the default naming/numbering schemes.